# linking C++ programs to Python

Tags: c++, python, wrapper

For linking C++ and python I used the following commands:

Compiling the actual function:

```
g++ -c -fpic main.cpp
```

Generate the wrapping C code using SWIG:

```
swig -c++ -python main.i
```

Compile the wrapping C code:

```
g++ -c -fpic main_wrap.cxx -I/usr/include/python2.7
```

for Linking everything together I used these tow instruction:

```
1)  g++ -shared main.o main_wrap.o -o _main.so 
2)  g++ -lpython -shared main.o main_wrap.o -o _main.so
```

and got errors in both but less in the second one. (for the func.c example I checked and it only be linked with -lpython flag be set!)
however, it still gives me following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > power_method<double>(double, int)", referenced from:
  __wrap_power_methodDouble in main_wrap.o
 "std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > power_method<float>(float, int)", referenced from:
  __wrap_power_methodFloat in main_wrap.o
"std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > power_method<int>(int, int)", referenced from:
  __wrap_power_methodInt in main_wrap.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
 Show message history
```

Comment: looks like there should be some library/object file that contains the vector implementation.

Comment: It looks a bit like you're compiling with g++ but linking with clang?

Comment: If you don't plan to use any languages other than C++ and Python, you may find Cython easier than SWIG.  If you're intending to do a number of high level languages, SWIG is a good choice.

Comment: @dstromberg: I don't have any control over clang! Do you expect another linker while compiling with g++? how should I skip the clang?